# Why did The Doctor start to regenerate at Lake Silencio?

Tags: doctor-who

When The Doctor is shot by the astronaut at Lake Silencio, he begins to regenerate, before being shot again and killed. But, at that point, he was

> *The Teselecta*, with the real Doctor safely miniaturized inside.

So why does his body start to generate as normal, with a ton of regeneration energy streaming off of him? How did he accomplish that without actually being injured and regenerating?

Comment: I remember this being discussed as part of another question, and the conclusion was that the Teselecta could mimic almost anything.  But I can't find that other question.  (That might mean this is a duplicate.)

Comment: @TangoOversway: The closest one I could find: [What happened in 'The Wedding of River Song'?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5952/2565). Do you mean that one?

Comment: @TangoOversway I don't remember seeing that mentioned but it does make sense; I'm not sure I buy that they can replicate *anything* as we only ever see them replicate shapes/forms, and never creating a "light show", but I guess that isn't all that big of a technological leap :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - have we seen the Teselectas other than the one that "killed" Hitler and the Doctor? (that was the same one, right?) I haven't seen all of S7 yet, so please no spoilers other than "yes" (or "no") for that please. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Keep in mind, as revealed in the most recent episode:

> When an event is observed or known, it becomes a fixed point in time and cannot be changed.

That being known,

> The events observed by Amy and Rory are then forced to take place, and they have to think that the Doctor is dead.

Thus,

> it would behoove the doctor to use the Teselecta to mimic a partial regeneration cycle to create the effect.

So we must conclude

> The Doctor was not regenerating at all, merely providing all witnesses with the effect of such.

Wow this is a hard one to answer without a crap-load of spoilers.

Comment: I'm mostly curious if anything we've ever seen him do anything like spoiler #3; we've seen some odd things with regeneration energy from Ten and Eleven (and River) but this seems like something much more extreme with nothing to trigger it.

Comment: The Teselecta is able to reproduce the appearance of anything. Using it to create a glow from the hands wouldn't be too difficult.